# How to pass ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

The thing is, that I need to return the books and their `COUNT`, which were in a possession of a reader less times than the `AVG` of all books being taken by readers. I have prepared this code:

```
SELECT book.name, book.publisher, COUNT(specimen.taken) FROM book
LEFT JOIN specimen ON book.isbn = specimen.isbn 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(specimen.taken) FROM specimen
GROUP BY specimen.isbn)  <
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(specimen.nr) / COUNT(specimen.taken) AS 
DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM specimen)
GROUP BY book.name, book.publisher;
```

but since the result of the first `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause returns the numbers of the times each book was taken, I cannot compare them with the overall average concluded by the second `SELECT`. Thus I get

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Is this the part where I should be using select within selects select or something? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your query is that you want a `HAVING` clause, not a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT b.name, b.publisher, COUNT(*)
FROM book b LEFT JOIN
     specimen s
     ON b.isbn = s.isbn 
GROUP BY b.name, b.publisher
HAVING COUNT(*) < (SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT s2.isbn) 
                   FROM specimen s2
                  );
```

You are not calculating the average correctly either.  The above is my best guess.

Note:  The "right" way to write the query uses window functions, but I'm guessing you have not learned that yet.

Comment: `The "right" way to write the query uses window functions, but I'm guessing you have not learned that yet.` You don't have to be disrespectful,  the aim of this forum is to search and receive help, no matter the level of the knowledge.